# CNTK: The new clone do not match the cloned inputs of the clonee Block Function

Tags: python, runtime-error, cntk

I have trained a model in CNTK. Then I clone it and change some parameters; when I try to test the quantized model, I get

> RuntimeError: Block Function 'softplus:  -> Unknown': Inputs
> 'Constant('Constant70738', [], []), Constant('Constant70739', [], []),
> Parameter('alpha', [], []), Constant('Constant70740', [], [])' **of the
> new clone do not match the cloned inputs** 'Constant('Constant70738',
> [], []), Constant('Constant70739', [], []), Constant('Constant70740',
> [], []), Parameter('alpha', [], [])' **of the clonee Block Function**.

I have no idea what this error means or how to fix it. Do you have any ideas?

P.S. I clone and edit the model by doing

> clonedModel = model.clone(cntk.ops.CloneMethod.clone)
>
> cloneModel.parameters[0].value = cloneModel.parameters[0].value*4

then when I try to use cloneModel I get that error above.

Answer (score 0):

This line

`cloneModel.parameters[0] = cloneModel.parameters[0]*4`

tries to replace the first parameter with an expression (a CNTK graph) that multiplies the parameter by 4. I don't think that's the intent here. Rather, you want to do the above on the `.value` attribute of the parameter. Try this instead:

`cloneModel.parameters[0].value = cloneModel.parameters[0].value*4`

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this way a mistake in the question I wrote; in the code I use .value. I fixed it in the question